# How to merge a BEDMatrix with a 'regular' matrix object in R

Tags: r, matrix, plink

I am dealing with a new R object class for me, a BEDMatrix object. I have created a BEDMatrix from the standard plink files. Now I want to merge it with a regular matrix object in R. I have tried the functions merge() and join(), but all of them seem not to support the BEDMatrix object. Here is the code:

```
#----------------------- creating BEDMatrix--------------------------------------
library(BGData)

chr29 <- BEDMatrix("path to plink file")

#--------------------------------reading excel file---------------------------------------

library(readxl)

sheets <- excel_sheets(path = 'path to excel file')

Excel_rawTAUINDanimalList <- read_excel(path = 'path to excel file', sheet = "rawTAUIND-animalList")

# -------------- changing excel file to matrx ----------------------------------------------

excel_matrix <- as.matrix(Excel_rawTAUINDanimalList)


# ------------------------ trying to merge ------------------------------------------------

merged <- merge(chr29, excel_matrix, by.x = 1, by.y = 1, all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

I get this error:

```
can't covert ‘structure("BEDMatrix", package = "BEDMatrix")’ to data.frame
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Qba Liu

Comment: Have you tried to first convert your `BEDMatrix` object to a matrix with `as.matrix`?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot yes I have and it works but it is extremely slow and the BEDMatrix object has the property that it is never read in its entirety into the memory, which enables handling of very big data. When I would convert the BEDMatrix object to a R matrix this property would be lost. Thanks for your comment.